# 404 error Github Pages and Middleman

Tags: github-pages, middleman

I cannot figure out why I am getting a 404 error at http://rachaelsalter.github.io

I am using Middleman and the middleman-deploy gem. Everything seemed to work fine with the deploy and I have an index.html file.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks you for your help David! This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing to a **user repository** (userName.github.io), so you need to deploy your generated code to master branch. [See github pages documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/).

In your `config.rb` file, you must change `deploy.branch` variable witch is `gh-pages` by default, to `master`

```
activate :deploy do |deploy|
  deploy.method = :git
  deploy.branch = 'master'
  # ... other deploy setup
end
```

If you're versioning your sources, you will have to move them to another branch like `sources`.